# Is pre 0.5.0 keccak256(a,b) equivalent to post 0.5.0 keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a,b))?

Tags: solidity, keccak, encoding, solidity-0.5.x

In pre 0.5.0 Solidity if you wanted to hash a some set of data you would do `keccak(a, b, c)`. Post 0.5.0 keccak only takes 1 arg and [it is suggested to use](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html#semantic-and-syntactic-changes) `keccak(abi.encodePacked(a,b,c))` instead

But are the two guaranteed to return the same result? I did some quick testing and it seems like they do, but is this something I can rely on?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they do. The easiest way to test it is by using [remix](http://remix.ethereum.org) and simply switching the complier version for both.

---

If you take a look at the [note in version 0.4.24 of the docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=keccak#abi-encoding-functions), you will see that this is true and the reason it was switched was to simply be more explicit.

> These encoding functions can be used to craft data for function calls without actually calling a function. Furthermore, `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, b))` is a more explicit way to compute `keccak256(a, b)`, which will be deprecated in future versions.